# Facebook link default image on root Wordpress

Tags: facebook, image, wordpress

I'm trying to change the image that gets placed whenever I or a friend links the root URL of my site onto Facebook.  For example, when I link therearenoroads.com on to Facebook it just pulls random pictures to be the thumbnail.  Is there a way to set this image to be specific?

On the debugger I get this error...

More Than One OG URL Specified: Object at URL 'http://therearenoroads.com' of type     'website' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values: http://therearenoroads.com, http://therearenoroads.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Set an `og:image` meta tag. http://ogp.me/

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/example.jpg" />
```

Comment: I've added 'code' <meta property="og:url" content="http://therearenoroads.com">
    <meta property="og:title" content="There Are No Roads">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="There Are No Roads">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Better Yourself">
    <meta property="og:type" content="Website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://therearenoroads.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Screen-shot-2013-06-05-at-2.26.51-PM.png">

Answer (score 0):

Debugger helped to find which meta tags to delete ... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug